# Cannot read Command Line Arguments into integer Array C

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to use command line arguments and have it read into an array however the complier is giving me this error:

`error: invalid initializer`

I know I need to use  `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` to use command line arguments and then I have it set like this to read into the array:

```
 int arr[] = atoi(argv[1]);
```

Not sure what I am missing as this always worked for me in the past. Any ideas?

Comment: `atoi` returns a single integer, if you really want an array, then you can do `int arr[] = { atoi(argv[1]) }`;

Comment: What is the purpose of the {} between atoi(argv[1])?

Comment: This creates an array with the values specified in the curly braces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are passing through the command line a series of number and you want
to have them in an array, then you can do this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "not enough arguments\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int arr[argc-1];

    for(size_t i = 0; i < argc - 1; ++i)
        arr[i] = atoi(argv[i+1]);

    ...

    return;
}
```

The reason why the conversion starts at `argv[i+1]` and not `argv[0]` is because
`argv[0]` has always the string that contains the file name of the executed
binary (more precisely the was you've passed the command in the shell), so
`argc` is always at least 1. That's why the dimension of `arr` is `argc-1`,
because for `n` arguments, `argc` will be `n+1`.

Also be aware that `atoi` does a poor job when it encounters an error, if the
string is not an integer, then `atoi` will return 0 and you have no idea whether
this is a legit number of an error in the conversion. Using [`strtol`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) is a
far better alternative:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "not enough arguments\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int arr[argc-1];
    char *endptr;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < argc - 1; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] = strtol(argv[i+1], &endptr, 0);

        if(*endptr != 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "The argument #%d is not a number\n", i+1);
            return 1; // error
        }
    }

    ...

    return;
}
```

This would give you a far better result, because it reacts to error from the
user.

Comment: Sorry I just saw the update. Ignore previous comment

Comment: @reeseboy07 I've updated my answer because I realized that what you are saying right  now, is what you wanted.